# Callback function with request method to third party API is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am a beginner to callback concept and looking for a solution to my problem.
I calling third party API using request package in node.js here is the code:

In reusable library file: **auth.js**

```
let getAuthToken = () => {
  let authToken;
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://<apiURL>/V1/auth_token',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic <token>'
    }
  };
  request(options, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else {
      authToken = JSON.parse(response.body);
    }
  });
  return authToken;
}
```

on my route: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/musics/authorize-account, I am calling my controller function named "**getAuthorizationToken()**"

controllerfile: **music.controller.js**

```
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

let getAuthorizationToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    let token = await auth.getAuthToken();
    console.log(auth.getAuthToken());
    res.send(token);
}
```

Problem is the controller function is getting executed completely and then the third party API is being called event I have added await to the function.
Do explain to me the problem I am facing and any workaround solution will be heartily helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` is only useful on promises. In your case your `getAuthToken` does not return an promise. But you can change it.

```
let getAuthToken = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let authToken;
    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://<apiURL>/V1/auth_token",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic <token>"
      }
    };
    request(options, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        rej(error);
      } else {
        authToken = JSON.parse(response.body);
        res(authToken);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

In addition you should also wrap your `await` in a `try / catch`

```
let getAuthorizationToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       let token = await auth.getAuthToken();
       console.log(token);
       return res.send(token);
    } catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
       return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

Instead of an 500 error you should send an different error code like:

- 400 Bad request: If there are some missing credentials like the token is missing
- 401 Unauthorized: If the token is wrong

Comment: Thank you @Ifaruku. But let's say I don't want to use the promise. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @LaurenSofe yes with only callbacks, but its ugly, you really want it to do with callbacks? promises and `async / await` syntax are made to determinate callbacks

Comment: It is true, but let's say there are multiple chains of reusable function and using all of there with promise, is it a good approach?

Comment: do you mean a chain like this https://hackernoon.com/photos/N0ENUd29UdNJCFcl7GnmZHdk2fA2-721ju348x ?

Comment: yea its better, here is a image how it would look like if you use callbacks. https://static.wixstatic.com/media/1cd646_b30f0844aa7e4265ad6895a4b39cede7~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_699,h_355,al_c/1cd646_b30f0844aa7e4265ad6895a4b39cede7~mv2.png its an example that shows the "callback hell". it looks very ugly compared to the async chainging doesnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a promise to be able to `await` something and have it work as expected:

```
let getAuthToken = () => {
  let authToken;
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://<apiURL>/V1/auth_token',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic <token>'
    }
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        authToken = JSON.parse(response.body);
        resolve(authToken);
      }
    });
  })
}
```